# Can't import modules is typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a folder structure like this:

```
src\
   components\
     Home\
       index.tsx
   redux\
     reducer.ts
   index.tsx
```

In `./index.tsx`

in have

```
export const App = <p> Hello World </p>
```

When i try to `import { App } from ../index.tsx` in `reducer.js` is say `App is undefined`

But if i `import Home from '../components/Home'` it works well.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Because you're `export const App` rather than `export default const App`, you'll need to import like ```import { App } from ../index.tsx```

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Is **export const App = <p> Hello World </p>** your exact code?

Comment: No but it's basically my code

Answer (score 0):

`import { App } from ../index`? You should import `js` rather than `jsx`. Which is, I suppose, compiled and stored next to your `.jsx` files. You can also update your webpack config in order to import jsx directly, not sure it's an option in this case.

Comment: I'm using typescript and react native.

Comment: yes, I got it. But typescript is still compiled into regular `.js`, which is what you want to import. When you import `../components/Home`, you don't specify the filename with its extention, so what gets imported is basically `../components/Home/index.js`